# Missing Text in Air Application Flex4+Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

I am running the same AIR application under windows, linux and Mac OSX
Windows and Linux look fine, but under mac OS-X the controls are not showing any text.
Button, Tooltips, Labels, Check boxes, everything is blank.
I just ported that app to Flex 4. Flex 3 versions of the same app on the same OSX machine works.

How can I get controls to show text under Max OSX?
Is this a font problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I migrated a user account from another machine into Snow Leopard. The solution seems to be to erase the fonts in ~/Library/Fonts (note that this is the USER font directory, not the system's):

http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10735681#10735681

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue specific to this Mac computer.
I will close the question since it won't really benefit anybody.